# Proyecto lectura de archivo y realizar varias opciones usando este

Tags: c++, c

Porque no puedo copilar o ejecutar el programa no entiendo en realidad si me pueden ayudar que es lpo que tengo mal en el codigo que he hecho es un menu sencillo digo yo y necesito ver porque no me copila o porque me salen esos errores si me falta alguna libreria o algo (si me pueden ayudar tambien con lo que es el menu de opciones me ayudarian bastante en realidad ya que creo que es un ejercicio algo grande en realida diria yo) pero ahora principalmente quiero saber porque no me ejecuta el codigo que es lo que estoy haciendo mal ahora en realidad

```
#include <iostream>
  #include <stdlib.h>
        
        using namespace std;
        
        int main(){
            do {
                int opc1,opc2;
         
                // Texto del menú que se verá cada vez
                cout << "Menu de Opciones" << endl;
                cout << "1.-Leer y cargar el archivo"<<endl;
                cout << "2.-Mostrar mastriz de palabras repetidas"<<endl;
                cout << "3.-Mostrar matriz de palabras repetidas en orden"<<endl;
                cout << "4.-Mostrar lista de palabras PALINDROMO"<<endl;
                cout << "5.-lista de palabras que son verbos"<<endl;
                cout << "6.-SALIR" << endl;
                cout << "Elija una opcion en orden gerarquico porfavor:";
            
                cin >> opc1;
                
                switch (opc1) {
                    case 1:
                        cout << "Nombre o direccion del documento:";
                        // Lista de instrucciones de la opción 1                
                        //void leerarchivo();
                       
                        break;
                        
                    case 2:
                        cout<<"La matriz es:"
                        // Lista de instrucciones de la opción 2                
                        //void matrizdepalabras();
                        
                        break;
                        
                    case 3:
                        cout<<"la matriz ordenada:";
                        // Lista de instrucciones de la opción 3                
                        //void matrizdepalabrasrepetidas();
                            
                        break;
                        
                    case 4:
                        cout<<"palabras palindromo:";
                        // Lista de instrucciones de la opción 4                
                        //void palabraspalindromo();
                                    
                        break;
                        
                    case 5:
                        cout<<"Lista de Verbos:";
                        // Lista de instrucciones de la opción 4                
                        //void listadeverbo();
                             
                        break;
                        
                    case 6:
                        cout<<"Seguro que quieres salir \n 1.-Si \n 2.-NO \N"
                        cin>>opc2
                        if(opc2=1)
                        {
                            return 0;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                          return main();  
                        }
                        break;
              
                }
                    
                
            } while (!=6);
             
        system("pause");
        
        }
```

Comment: _No deja co**m**pilar_: ¿Qué errores te da? Además, dale un título más descriptivo a tu pregunta. Y recordá que existen los signos de puntuación :)

Comment: Cuáles son los errores? Por qué dices que no te deja compilar? Por favor, edita la pregunta y cuéntanos qué errores encuentras. Copia y pega los errores

Comment: Estas usando c++ entonces por qué colocas la etiqueta de [tag:c]???

Comment: En tu pregunta anterior te pase un par de links para que revisaras e hicieras mejor tus preguntas... que veo que no leiste... tenes un error, buenisimo... y como esperas que sepamos como ayudarte, si no decis cual es tu error?

Comment: Es ilegal llamar a `main`, no lo digo yo, lo dice el estándar.

Comment: esto: return main();   suena muy pero muy raro....

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster ya entendi lo que queria hacer.. quiere volver a reiniciar pero se le escapa porque el while mira la opcion.. en lugar de cambiar la opcion a cualquier cosa dentro del if... volvio a llamar a main...

Comment: @gbianchi lleva varias preguntas intentando resolver su ejercicio, en lugar de entender lo que le escriben o los errores que recibe se dedica a hacer una nueva pregunta con el nuevo problema que encuentra sin haber resuelto las cosas que preguntó anteriormente. Es frustrante intentar ayudar a quien no quiere aprender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu codigo debería de verse tal que así :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int menu() {
    int opc1;
    do {
        int opc2;

        // Texto del menú que se verá cada vez
        cout << "Menu de Opciones" << endl;
        cout << "1.-Leer y cargar el archivo" << endl;
        cout << "2.-Mostrar mastriz de palabras repetidas" << endl;
        cout << "3.-Mostrar matriz de palabras repetidas en orden" << endl;
        cout << "4.-Mostrar lista de palabras PALINDROMO" << endl;
        cout << "5.-lista de palabras que son verbos" << endl;
        cout << "6.-SALIR" << endl;
        cout << "Elija una opcion en orden gerarquico porfavor:";

        cin >> opc1;

        switch (opc1) {
        case 1:
            cout << "Nombre o direccion del documento:";
            // Lista de instrucciones de la opción 1                
            //void leerarchivo();

            break;

        case 2:
            cout << "La matriz es:";
            // Lista de instrucciones de la opción 2                
            //void matrizdepalabras()
            break;

        case 3:
            cout << "la matriz ordenada:";
            // Lista de instrucciones de la opción 3                
            //void matrizdepalabrasrepetidas();

            break;

        case 4:
            cout << "palabras palindromo:";
            // Lista de instrucciones de la opción 4                
            //void palabraspalindromo();

            break;

        case 5:
            cout << "Lista de Verbos:";
            // Lista de instrucciones de la opción 4                
            //void listadeverbo();

            break;

        case 6:
            cout << "Seguro que quieres salir \n 1.-Si \n 2.-NO \N";
            cin >> opc2;
            if (opc2 == 1)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                opc1 = 0;
                cout << "\n"; 
            }
            break;

        }

    } while (opc1 != 6);
    return 1;
}
int main() {
    system("pause");
    menu();
}
```

Te recomiendo que teniendo aquí la solución compares este archivo con el tuyo para darte cuenta de los errores.

Primero de todo, te has olvidado muchos `;` y siempre se debe finalizar con `;`, de lo contrario te generará error.

Siguiente, tenias `int opc1` dentro del `do` cuando deberia de estar fuera. Puedes seguir utilizando la variable dentro del `do` de todas formas...

El motivo por el que te he puesto la variable `opc1` fuera de tu bucle es por es tercer error.

El tercer error que has cometido es bastante grave... Tenias la sentencia `while` de esta forma `while !=6` cuando esta sentencia tiene que cumplir la siguiente sintaxis :

`while ALGO cumple OTRO`

Pongamos el siguiente ejemplo :

```
int a = 0;
while (a != 10) {
   cout << a;
   a += 1;
}
```

Aquí decimos que mientras que la variable `a` no sea igual a 10 se haga un console out de su valor. Seguido de esto se suma 1 al valor de a.

Para que lo entiendas mejor, `a += 1;` es lo mismo que decir `a = a +1;`

En caso de que no aumentes el valor de las variables causarás un bucle infinito porque la variable `a` siempre será mas pequeña que 10.

Tampoco es correcto que hagas esto:

```
else {
   return main();  
}
```

Te recomiendo que siempre encuentres otra forma de buscar lo que quieras hacer menos llamar a la función `main()` de nuevo. Nunca será correcto...

Por esto mismo se llama a otra la función `menu()`